# How to override django local Installed app in saleor platform

Tags: python-3.x, django, saleor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHHD9.png)

Hello here are some locally installed app in saleor platform.

Now I have to make chnages (override) some codes inside this apps.

what are the best practices or how can i do without in disturbance in existing code.

Thanks

I have tried to overide by following blog But got no result.